# Prevent default click event on VML shape with href

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, vml

I have a  VML shape in which I'm trying to prevent the browser from navigating to the `href`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<style type="text/css">
#a, #b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
#a {
    left: 10px;
    background: red;
}
#b { left: 120px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() { 

document.namespaces.add('v', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml', '#default#VML');

window.onload = function() {

    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    a.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
        console.log('A');
        e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    });

    var b = document.getElementById('b');
    b.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
        console.log('B');
        e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    });

};

})();
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="a" href="/foo"></a>
        <v:rect id="b" href="/bar"><v:fill color="#0000ff" /></v:rect>
    </body>
</html>
```

Run this sample in IE8. Clicking on the link (the red shape) properly prevents browser from going to `/foo` with `returnValue = false/return false`.

However, attempting to cancel the navigation on the `<v:rect>` **does not work**. The browser navigates to `/bar`!

Is there a solution to get around this?

Comment: can you also try `cancelBubble` (from `internet explorer equivalents` section of http://www.brainjar.com/dhtml/events/default3.asp)

Comment: @roberkules - woops forgot to say that `cancelBubble=true` also does not work.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky: Try modifying the event via `window.event` instead from the event handler's parameter to set the `returnValue`.

Comment: @Jay - I had tried that earlier too, and I just did it again, but that didn't work either (adding `window.event.returnValue = false; window.event.cancelBubble = true;` to the `b` click handler).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var b = document.getElementById('b');
b.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```